# How does one get Coordinates from a given address from the OpenStreetMaps API

Tags: java, jersey

So this Question might seem very trivial to some of you but bear with me please, I'm a beginner in these things.
I'm trying to make a desktop application using Java that fetches all sorts of geo information from API's that (to my knowledge) all stem from the OpenStreetMaps developers.
In the first step of my Workflow I want to make a sort of "navigation" logic.
I need the distance between two addresses and I know how to get that distance but for that to work I need to first convert those addresses into longlat coordinates.
Now the code:

```
public static String getLongLat(String address) {
    String temp = "";

    JSONObject longlat = makeRequest("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q="+address+"&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1","get");
    String lon = longlat.getString("lon");
    String lat = longlat.getString("lat");

    System.out.println(lon);
    System.out.println(lat);

    return temp;
}
```

I'm not yet doing anything major with the returned information because there is none. Now if I go and type that exact URL into my browser bar it gives me a nicely formatted JSON view and I can see all the details I need, including coordinates and bounds. But if I execute this little code snippet it returns with a message saying "301 - Moved permanently" and I don't really get why or how to fix this so my Java Application gets a proper JSON result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `GET` request for this URL returns a `301 Moved Permanently` response that points to

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Berlin&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1
```

Note the use of `https` instead of `http`.